# How can I override the 'unique' error on a ModelForm field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.6

I'm trying to override the 'unique' error message for a Field in my ModelForm. I'm trying to follow the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) for Django 1.6, but I can't get it to work. Pretty simple stuff, I have:

models.py:

```
class EmailAddress(Model):
    """An email address."""
    address = EmailField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.address
```

views.py:

```
class EmailAddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmailAddress
        fields = {'address'}
        error_messages = {
            'address': {
                u'unique': _('That address has already been added.'),
            }
        }
```

If I enter a duplicate email, I get:

```
emailaddress_form.errors = {'address': [u'Email address with this Address already exists.']}.`
```

I've dug around in the source code, and as far as I can tell I'm passing the `error_messages` dict correctly into where it'll be picked up by the `django.forms.models.fields_for_model` function called by the Metaclass. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This :-

Change address field to :-

address = models.EmailField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"That address has already been added."})

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that uses the ModelForm error_messages attribute, but this is the closest and simplest workaround until Django fixes that apparent bug.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method "clean_address" on EmailAddressForm class, hopefully  This will resolved your issue.

```
def clean_address(self):
  """Prevent duplicate email addresses."""
  if 'email' in self.changed_data:
      if self.Meta.model.all().filter('address =', self.cleaned_data['address']).count():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email address with this Address already exists.: %s.' %
                                     self.cleaned_data['address'])
  return self.cleaned_data['address']
```